# mysql : can't have the max result

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

i've got a problem with my mysql request, i have this table :

| col1 | id_sec | _index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 20 | 3 |
| 111 | 50 | 0 |
| 111 | 60 | 1 |
| 111 | 20 | 2 |
| 111 | 20 | 1 |
| 111 | 20 | 0 |
| 111 | 60 | 0 |

i would like to have :

| col1 | id_sec | _index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 60 | 1 |
| 111 | 50 | 0 |
| 111 | 20 | 3 |

but i have :

| col1 | id_sec | _index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 20 | 0 |
| 111 | 50 | 0 |
| 111 | 60 | 0 |

my request is :

```
select * 
from ( select * 
       from test 
       WHERE col1 = 111
       order by id_sec, _index desc
     ) t2 
group by id_sec
```

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT col1, id_sec, MAX(_index) _index
FROM table
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1e1155442ac7dcf3f54ba1fee5228078

Comment: Hi !
Thanks but it does not work, it just ordering my table by id_sec and _index columns... i have the 7 rows instead of 3.

Comment: @Riwalenn I don't understand where it was possible to make a mistake here... but you succeeded. PS. Fiddle added.

Comment: ok i see what my mistake is.. i never know that you can group by or order with numbers. Can you just explain to me what column 1 or 2 represante in this case ? is it the order in the select ?
Thank by the way it work...

Comment: Ok i did some test and i see now. Thanks a lot for the help. (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: @Riwalenn https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html Columns selected for output can be referred to in ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses using column names, column aliases, or column positions. Column positions are integers and begin with 1.

Comment: @Riwalenn  column aliases / positions can be used not for clear columns only but for output expressions of any complexity too. Position can be used even when the expression is not assigned with an alias.